# FileDiffEngine from FileHelpers Lib fails after upgrade

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have upgraded the FileHelpers Library from 2.0 to the latest 3.1.5 but now the FileDiffEngine does not work anymore.

Code:

```
var engine = new FileDiffEngine(typeof(CustomClass));
```

Compiler Error:

> Using the generic type 'FileHelpers.FileDiffEngine' requires 1 type argument

Why I am getting this error? The code above is working in Version 2.0 and I am supplying 1 type argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [now specify the type as a generic placeholder](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FileDiffEngine_1.htm):

```
var engine = new FileDiffEngine<CustomClass>();
```